# R Colorize several graphs in different colors in matplot()

Tags: r, plot

I have several graphs that I want to colorize.

code for exapmle

```
X <- sapply(1:3,\(x) cumsum(rnorm(200)))

col <- sample(2:4,nrow(X),replace = T) |> sort()

plot(X[,1],t="p",ylim = range(X),col=col,pch=20)
lines(X[,2],t="p",col=col,pch=20)
lines(X[,3],t="p",col=col,pch=20)
```

[image]

How can I do the same using the `matplot` function?
I tried different options but never succeeded.

```
matplot(X,t="p",lty=1,col=col,pch=20)

matplot(X,t="p",lty=1,col=cbind(col,col,col),pch=20)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `matplot` function? That function works well if each of your columns are supposed to be a different color, but here you are changing the color within each series which is a bit unusual. This means the point/color values can't be put in a rectangular matrix so it's not a good "mat"rix for "matplot"

Comment: Well, I was hoping there was a solution like 'col=cbind(col,col,col)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you want to use `matplot` here at all. You could easily do the same with `plot` in one line:

```r
plot(rep(seq(nrow(X)), ncol(X)), X, col = col, pch = 20, xlab = "")
```

[image]

If for some reason you *have* to use `matplot`, you could do:

```r
lapply(1:4, function(x) {
  if(x == 1) matplot(X, type = 'n') else {
    X[!col %in% x,] <- NA
    matplot(X, col = x, add = TRUE, pch = 20)
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I still hoped that this could be done in one line and without loops, but apparently there is no such option

Comment: @mr.T you can certainly plot it in one line - see my update.